# DependencyInjection in AbstractEntity

Tags: php, symfony, autowired

i started working on a new **Symfony 6.0** project.

I created a new Entity called `Project`. In this entity I want to set the `created_by` property automaticlly on `PrePersist` (hook) call...
Therefore I created an `AbstractEntity` to extend the original `Project` entity.

In `AbstractEntity` I want to automatically inject `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security` service.

BUT the autowire stuff just doesn't work.

```yaml
# config/services.yaml
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/' # --> i removed that line (doesnt work)
            - '../src/Kernel.php'

    #this also does not work
    App\Entity\AbstractEntity:
        autowire: true

    #this also does not work
    App\Entity\AbstractEntity:
        arguments:
            - '@security.helper'
```

```php
// src/Entity/AbstractEntity.php
<?php 

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

#[ORM\MappedSuperclass]
#[ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks]
abstract class AbstractEntity
{
    private $security;

    public function __construct(Security $security)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entity should not have any dependencies and contain logic. If you want to do something, consider creating [Doctrine Lifecycle Listeners](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html#doctrine-lifecycle-listeners) `prePersist` or [Doctrine Entity Listeners](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html#doctrine-entity-listeners).

---

> Lifecycle listeners are defined as PHP classes that listen to a single
> Doctrine event on all the application entities.

---

Add to services.yaml file

```
App\EventListener\CreatedByLifecycleEvent:
    tags:
        -
            name: 'doctrine.event_listener'
            event: 'prePersist'
```

And create a listener

```
namespace App\EventListener;
 
use Doctrine\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class CreatedByLifecycleEvent
{
    private $security;
    public function __construct(Security $security)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args): void
    {
        $entity = $args->getObject();
        if(method_exists($entity,'setCreatedBy') and !empty($user = $this->security->getUser())){
            $entity->setCreatedBy($user);
        }
    } 
}
```

---

Thus, when saving any entity, provided that the `setCreatedBy` method exists, our listener will set the current user.